# Printing different arrays in one for loop

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I have a number of List, each List is converted to array using `.ToArray()` method. Each array size varies and the name of arrays are `DataArray0`, `DataArray1`, `DataArray2`------`DataArrayN`. I want to print the values of these arrays in for loop such that I don't have to write multiple `Console.WriteLine` statements for each array.

Is there any way in C# that I can write something like:

```
for (int jj = 0; jj < colCount; jj++)
{
    for (int jjj = 0; jjj < rowCount; jjj++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DataArray+[jj]+[jjj]);
    }
}
```

I want it to print out data first for `DataArray0`, then `DataArray1` and so on.
The code is just for better view of my question. I know the print statement will give error.

Comment: Try using recursion for your printing method..

Comment: Can you show an example of the data structure that you have, so the people won't just imagine what are you trying to iterate on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create array of arrays and add additional loop.

Then to print element at some position for every array:

```
var arrays = new DataArray[] { DataArray0, DataArray1, ...} // use correct type

for (int jj = 0; jj < colCount; jj++)
{
    for (int jjj = 0; jjj < rowCount; jjj++)
    {
        for (var arrayIndex = 0; arrayIndex < arrays.Length; a++)
        {  
            Console.WriteLine(arrays[arrayIndex][jj][jjj]);
        }
    }
}
```

**OR**

To print one array after another:

```
for (var arrayIndex = 0; arrayIndex < arrays.Length; a++)
{
    for (int jj = 0; jj < colCount; jj++)
    {
        for (int jjj = 0; jjj < rowCount; jjj++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(arrays[arrayIndex][jj][jjj]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So from what I gather you have a list of lists (or arrays, doesn't matter).

You can iterate over them using foreach:

```
var list_of_lists = new List<List<int>>{
    new List<int>{1,2},
    new List<int>{3,4,5},

};

foreach (var item in list_of_lists)
{
    foreach (var nested_item in item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(nested_item);
    }
}
```